# Trigger Sitecore event programmatically

Tags: c#, sitecore

My sitecore website subscribes to the OnSave event of the content change. When I log into the content manager and change any of the fields, then the event is successfully triggered on the website. Now, I'm trying to do the same thing, except trigger this event from a standalone console app.

The code below changes the content and I'm able to see the change on the website, but the OnSave event is not triggered. The edit context is not silent, so it should trigger the event but it isn't.

I also checked the event quote database and the new event is being created but its just not being triggered on the web. Does anyone have a clue on why the event is not being triggered?

```
Pipeline.Start("initialize", new PipelineArgs(), true);

// get database
string domainUser = @"sitecore\admin";

if (Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.Exists(domainUser))
{
    Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User user =
    Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User.FromName(domainUser, false);

    using (new Sitecore.Security.Accounts.UserSwitcher(user))
    {
        var db = Factory.GetDatabase("master");
        Item ii = db.SelectSingleItem("/sitecore/content/Home");

        using (new EditContext(ii, true, false))
        {
            String current = ii.Fields["Breadcrumb Title"].Value;
            Console.WriteLine("Current value: " + current);
            current += " e";
            Console.WriteLine("Changing to: " + current);

            ii.Fields["Breadcrumb Title"].Value = current;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The use of EditContext is deprecated. The correct and supported way to edit items is to use Item.Editing.BeginEdit() and Item.Editing.EndEdit(). First thing to try is to switch to those, and see if it makes a difference.

Meanwhile; you say the event is not being triggered "on the web". Are you in a multi-server setup?  If so, you need to consider the remote events, as "item:saved" would only trigger on the actual server where the event was triggered.

Comment: I tried using Item.Editing and that didnt make a difference. By "on the web" I meant the website. Right now I'm working in the dev environment, so we're using sitecore master (nothing published). And the console app is running on the same machine as well

Comment: Ok. Well I guess the clue then would be, it does not look like you're running Sitecore in any "normal" kind of web context. The reason I say this is; you're doing Console.WriteLine for your debugging purposes. I do remember reading some posts about how to get Sitecore to run outside of a traditional HttpContext (for testing and mocking purposes) - but all of the methods I have seen, severely alters how Sitecore functions. I would not expect normal Sitecore events to trigger and function like you would normally expect, if running in the context of these methods.

Comment: Can you share any information about how your dev environment is configured?  If so, I might be able to assist further.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your help. In my Dev envt, I have SiteCore running in IIS in standalone mode. The whole reason I'm using a console app is because there is some data that we cache on the website that I need cleared. Do you think there is some other better way of doing this? Once this goes into prod, we'll have multiple webservers that'll need to flush the cache.

Comment: You can you not write a web service on the master that you call into from the console app? Have all you logic there, that way you'll have no issues with Sitecore context.

Comment: As @jammykam says; the best way of doing what you're after, is to write a web service to call into, and have it run in a normal web/Sitecore context. That would ensure events get fired and everything else working as expected.